# How to call a function when its arguments come from different places

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I want to call a function (showResult), but each of its required arguments comes from different places. I have to wait until an event handler (server sends a response) for the price, but don't know how I'm supposed to pass the other required argument (product).

EDIT: To clarify, server.onResponse is referring to websocket connection's "onmessage" event handler ( [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/onmessage) )

```
function requestPhoneCost () {
    var product = "iPhone 7";
    server.requestPrice(product);
}

server.onResponse(function(response) {
   //response contains only information about the price, but not
   //what product its for

   showResult( , response.price);

});

function showResult (product, cost) {
   alert(product + " costs " + response + "dollars");
}
```

Comment: save the price to a variable and lower down your code, assign it to the function along with whatever else you want

Comment: Since `server` apparently A) Is shared, and B) Does its work asynchronously, my advice is: Don't make it shared. Create one as needed. What is `server`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky An option that attaches the product to the call would likely be the preferred alternative. Storing a global variable across multiple calls could get hairy if they overlap.

Comment: @TylerRoper Doesn't have to be global, It could be within a certain scope as a let. If he needs to have a global, just make sure he doesn't create a bunch of them. one global is fine.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - You still have the same problem: If two parts of the code both call `requestPrice` on two separate products and those calls overlap, boom.

Comment: Ideally, this is an async/await scenario: `server.requestPrice(product).then(price=>{showResult(product, price);})`

Comment: Ah I see. Then use async and await or a promise.

Comment: @RandyCasburn post that as an answer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky & Randy - But not with `server` as shown, since it has just the one central `onResponse` thing. Which is the primary problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder more specifically, it's a websocket connection

Comment: @Jabberwocky - TJ's comment is why I didn't post as answer. we don't have enough info.

Comment: The onresponse was referring to a websocket connection's "onmessage" handler. I parse the message based on what type of information it's returning and from there call the functions I need. (i.e. showResult)

Comment: @sorrySneezy - We need more information about `server` to be able to help you.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - And that was wise of you. :-) I wasn't as wise.

Comment: @sorrySneezy - I've updated my answer to account for having just a single shared `onResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the response function within the `requestPhoneCost` function, so it can access `product` in the closure.

```
function requestPhoneCost() {
  var product = "iPhone 7";
  server.requestPrice(product);
  server.onResponse(function(response) {
    showResult(product, response.price);
  });
}

function showResult(product, cost) {
  alert(product + " costs " + response + "dollars");
}
```

This assumes that `server.onResponse()` replaces the response event listener, rather than adding an additional listener.

Comment: I don't know if that won't just keep attaching more and more callbacks that would be fired `onResponse`. Or if it's only a single persistent one, then a second call could trample the previous handler that was set. Not sure without knowing what `server` and/or `server.onResponse` does.

Comment: If it's cumulative then I think he has a more general problem, since nothing removes the handler he wrote.

Comment: This is my fault for not including this in the original question, but server.onResponse refers to the onMessage handler of a websocket connection https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/onmessage. It's already been declared in the constructor of the connection and the message handling takes care of different of messages. So I'm not sure I can change where I declare it.

Comment: Well, that's a poor design if you need to maintain state between the request and response.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem here is `server`. It's apparently a shared resource, but it has just a single callback that is called with responses. That design won't work.

Instead, have server accept the callback for a specific call **with** the request. Then doing what you're looking for is trivial:

```
function requestPhoneCost () {
    var product = "iPhone 7";
    server.requestPrice(product, cost => showResult(product, cost));
}
```

In today's world, I would use promises rather than a manually-coded callback:

```
function requestPhoneCost () {
    var product = "iPhone 7";
    server.requestPrice(product)
    .then(cost => showResult(product, cost))
    .catch(error => { /* handle/report error */);
}
```

In both cases this requires changing `server` so it keeps track of which callbacks relate to which requests. That sounds a lot harder than it is (it's actually really easy), but we can't help you with code we can't see (e.g., `server`'s code).

You've said you have a central `onResponse` set up in the constructor of a websocket connection. IIRC, every message on a websocket has a unique ID (and if not, presumably you can add one). You can then store information about the promise you returned for the request in a `Map` keyed by that ID:

```
this.id = 0; // If you need to assign your own IDs
this.settlersById = new Map();
```

Here's a conceptual `requestPrice` method in your server class:

```
requestPrice(product) {
    const id = ++this.id;
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sendRequest({id, product});
        this.settlersById.set(id, {resolve, reject});
    });
}
```

then in onResponse

```
onResponse(response) {
    const {id} = response;
    const settlers = this.settlersById.get(id;
    if (settlers) {
        this.settlersById.delete(id);
        if (/* response is a success */) {
            resolve(response.data);
        } else {
            reject(/*...appropriate error...*/);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, this is all conceptual, since we don't have your server class. And it's using its own ID, whereas websockets may provide one for you.

Comment: Your detailed answer is much appreciated. Dumb question, but where in my code am I setting this.id and this.settlersbyid?

Comment: @sorrySneezy - :-) I don't believe in dumb questions. (Okay, I admit it, I've seen some, but this isn't one of them.) In the constructor of your server class.

Comment: I'll have to do some reading up on how exactly promises work, and I'll try implementing your suggestions. Thanks :)